# any-word search using LIKE %

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search, sql-like

I have a database table which has a field `firstname` and a field `lastname`. I'm trying to implement an any-word search system using a search box where if let's say that we have a user named `John Stanley Smith` in the database (where `firstname = John Stanley` and `lastname = Smith`), I want to be able to return `John Stanley Smith` if the user types any of the following:

1- Any letter which is part of `John Stanley Smith` (j, s, l, e, y, m, etc...)
2- Any word which is part of `John Stanley Smith`
3- Any combination of words (in any order) which is part of `John Stanley Smith`, meaning that, if the user enters either `John Stanley` or `John Smith` or `Stanley Smith` or `Stanley John` (you get the idea) etc... I want to be able to find `John Stanley Smith`.

I know I can do this using the [MySQL Fulltext Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) feature, but if I do, point number one will not work (because the MySQL fulltext search feature only matches whole words, not substrings within a string). Also, there is a minimum number of words required for the search to be performed (set by the `min_word_len` constant). So, I really want to do this using LIKE %.

Thank you

Comment: Not possible with a simple query - you'll have to do some hideously ugly query building to do `where like '%j%' or like '%o%' or like '%h%' etc...` or a series of instr() calls and the like. performance is likely to be utterly hideous and have massive false positives

Comment: I can't think of a ready made solution, but I guess using some regular expression (and maybe a few UNIONs): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 0):

I might have misunderstood but have you considered just doing this:

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE
    CONCAT(firstname, " ", lastname) LIKE '%$pattern%'
```

if the user enters more than one word, separated by whitespaces, simple split the string into words and modify the query to

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE
    CONCAT(firstname, " ", lastname) LIKE '%$word1%'
 OR CONCAT(firstname, " ", lastname) LIKE '%$word2%'
 OR CONCAT(firstname, " ", lastname) LIKE '%$word3%'
 ...
```

Comment: I can't keep track of the number of words the user will enter (I mean, the user might enter 2, 3 or 15 words), so I don't know for how long I'm going to have to do CONCAT... OR CONCAT... OR CONCAT.... OR CONCAT.... etc

Comment: Use a loop to generate the query. `$words = array("word1", "word2"); foreach($words as $word) $query .= "OR CONCAT(firstname, " ", lastname) LIKE '%".esc($word)."%'";`

Comment: but what happens if for example the user enters 4 words `John Stanley Smith Thomas`? This breaks. Basically all I want is to return the data that contains at least one of the words or characters entered

Comment: if you use OR like i did in the example, every tuple that contains at least one of the words will be in the result. so `John Stanley Smith Thomas` will match any of those and more `John`, `John Smith`, `Thomas Stanley`, ... Naveen has formatted this approach for you a little more, but use `OR` to implode, not `AND` or only tuples that have **all** the words will match.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
$whereclauses=array();

$terms = explode(' ', $search_term);
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $term = mysql_real_escape_string($term);
    $whereclauses[] = "CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE '%$term%'";
}
$sql = "select * from table where";
$sql .= implode(' and ', $whereclauses);
```