# MySqli query like any values in a PHP array

Tags: php

I have a PHP array containing values and I want to query the database to find any results where the `ItemName` contains any of the values in the array.

```
$current_item = 'Big Fancy Red Car';

$words = explode(' ',$current_item); // Array of words to search
```

And the query:

```
SELECT ID FROM store_accessories WHERE ItemName LIKE '%$words%'
```

How do I select the ID of any items in the table whose `ItemName` contains any of the values in the `$words` array?

Comment: What is the table engine of `store_accessories`? If possible, a FULLTEXT index is an ideal solution, available in MyISAM tables before MySQL 5.6, and InnoDB after.

Comment: See also [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406200/any-word-search-using-like) which build up a long string of `column LIKE %$word% OR...` conditions. Considerably less efficient than a FULLTEXT index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

1. First explode the value into an array:

`$terms = explode(' ', $search_term);`

2. Loop the array to add the `LIKE`

`foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $term = mysql_real_escape_string($term);
        $likes[] = "field LIKE '%$term%'";
    }`

3. Add to the query:

`$sql = "select * from table where";
$sql .= implode(' OR ', $likes);`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `LIKE` like this directly, also substituting `'` with `''` and escaping `_` and `%`:

```
$field = "ItemName";
$like = "$field LIKE '%".str_replace(
   array("'" , "_"  , "%"  , " "                   ),
   array("''", "\\_", "\\%", "%' OR $field LIKE '%"),
   $currentItem)."%'";
```